# How to Capture Screenshots at 15fps in Unity for FirstPersonCharacter Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to capture screenshots from  Camera of FirstPerson character in unity.

My current script is enabling me to capture a screenshot every 1 second . But I want screenshots every 1/15th of a second. I have no clue how would I be able to do it.The following is the C# script for the same.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SS : MonoBehaviour
{
 public int resWidth = 640; 
 public int resHeight = 480;
 public int fps=15;
 private float videoTime=0;
 private bool takeHiResShot = false;

 public static string ScreenShotName(int width, int height) {
     return string.Format("{0}/screenshots/screen_{1}x{2}_{3}.png", 
                          Application.dataPath, 
                          width, height, 
                          System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
 }

 public void TakeHiResShot() {
     takeHiResShot = true;
 }
 void Update(){
        videoTime += Time.deltaTime;

        if (videoTime >= (1f / (float)fps)) {
            Debug.LogFormat(videoTime.ToString());
            videoTime = 0;
            takeHiResShot=true;

             if (takeHiResShot) {
         RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
         GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = rt;
         Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
         GetComponent<Camera>().Render();
         RenderTexture.active = rt;
         screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
         GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = null;
         RenderTexture.active = null; // JC: added to avoid errors
         Destroy(rt);
         byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
         string filename = ScreenShotName(resWidth, resHeight);
         System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
         Debug.Log(string.Format("Took screenshot to: {0}", filename));
         takeHiResShot = false;
     }
 }
}
}
```

I am getting screenshots with timestamp. Each  screenshot is differing from its consecutive screenshot by one second.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the bug is pretty simple, the way you name your files is **"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"** which means all the files created within 1 second will simply overwrite each other. So try **"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss.ffff"** instead. It should solve the problem.

Having said that, it seems pretty tough taking 15 high res screenshots per second, I doubt any home pc will handle it easily without a noticeable slowdown. If you need a video, maybe consider actually recording a video, this is much less resource consuming? There are some free plugins for that on the asset store. You may have your own reasons for doing this though if you know what you are doing, I don't know.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Actually I don't need a video .I need multiple screenshots at 15 fps for my project so that I could do further processing on it outside Unity.Is there any other way ,I mean is there something like 15fps video? That might be noob question but I would like to know more if something like that exists

Comment: You could try this plugin: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/unity-recorder-94079 Target frame rate is configurable with it.

Comment: If you don't really need the highest precision with each screenshot, taking video even at 30fps will be still more efficient then saving full image for each frame. Just remember that everything has its drawbacks, recording video will probably lose some image quality. Anyway, even if you decide to stick with full screenshots, writing to disk can be done asynchronously (currently you wait on each frame for file write to finish).

Comment: Thanks Yuri , I will look into it